# Passing mocked static method to another class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I have mocked a static method of a class using Powermock in my test class. The problem I face is that this static method is not called directly in my test class, but in some other class. Here is the skeleton:

```
@Test public void myTest() { 
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClassWithStaticMethod.class);
    PowerMockito.when(MyClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod()).thenReturn("...");
    List<String> details = MyHelperClass.getDetails();
    ...
    ...
}
```

Now MyHelperClass.getDetails calls the method that needs to be mocked as it is dependent upon a service.

MyHelperClass.java

```
public static List<String> getDetails() {
    ...
    ...
    MyObj obj = MyClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod(); //This needs to return mocked value
    ...
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to pass the mocked object to the helper class? PowerMockito.mockStatic returns void, where as PowerMockito.mock doesn't mock the static methods. So I am not able to figure out how to pass the mocked object to the helper class getDetails() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerMock isn't really capable of what you're willing to achieve. There's another mocking framework, that can mock literally almost everything by instrumenting the bytecode - [JMockit](http://jmockit.org/)

As for your problem - perhaps [that](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#staticFactories) would help

Comment: Thanks a ton! At first I was hesitant to use JMockit as mockito was already being used and I wanted to figure out a solution by using PowerMock with mockito. I ran into a few issues getting JMockit running - had to upgrade my Junit to 4.12 as JMockit only supports JUnit 4.5+ (its a plus, but I hope Junit 4.4 tests in our code didn't have something that isn't supported in 4.12). But all the trouble was completely worth to become friends with such a beauty that JMockit is! :)

Comment: The test should be easier to write with JMockit, but it should also work fine with PowerMock. I wonder if the OP forgot to use `@PrepareForTest` on the test class?

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple note regarding static methods - since this kind of methods is harder to stub and since stubbing them can potentially affect other tests, I recommend adding unit tests for them and relying on those tests instead of trying to make sure the method is called.
The reason I'm advocating on this approach is that static methods should consist only of utility methods, which once tested can be relied upon. And also checking method calls always introduces coupling between your code and the unit tests, resulting in headaches when thinking about refactoring, as application code refactoring leads to lots of unit tests needing changes.